# Как исправить результат cURL на сайте работающем по http протоколу?

Tags: curl

С помощью cURL пытаюсь получить содержимое страницы, пример страницы https://mt4trendindicator.com

Мой сайт работает без ssl по http протоколу, в результате я получаю ошибку `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` и протокол моего сайта при этом изменяется на https протокол, хотя ssl у меня не установлен.

Добавил в код строки

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

но ничего не изменилось.

В чем может быть проблема, почему страница открывается по https протоколу?

p.s. большинство url открываются корректно за исключением указанного выше.

https://yandex.ru легко открывается на моем сайте работающем по http протоколу без установки ssl.

Comment: Вы прикладываете ссылку на сайт с https и пишете что он работает по http.

Comment: Другие сайты с https легко работают на http сайте. Еще есть сайты которые открывают просто белую страницу, я давно работаю с curl но с подобными проблемами не сталкивался :(

Comment: Из вашего вопроса сложно понять при чём здесь собственно ваш сайт.

Comment: Я тоже не понимаю, почему протокол моего сайта изменяется на https после выполнения cURL.

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста подробнее откуда вы запускаете PHP скрипт и что вы называете "мой сайт"

Comment: Мой сайт - мой домен. PHP запускаю с сервера vps (со своего домена-сайта). 90% запросов срабатывают, но некоторые открывают белую страницу либо `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` в строке браузера при этом мой сайт открывается по https протоколу, хотя обращение к скрипту идет по http

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вы открываете в браузере страницу, которая ведёт на PHP на вашем сайте, который запрашивает через curl другой сайт, результат запроса на который возвращается в браузер? Если так, то там возможно просто редирект на https. Попробуйте для curl поиграться с (CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE)

Comment: Да, все верно. (CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE) не помогло. Мне еще нужно по редиректам переходить. Страница начинает грузиться, появляется title но дальше редиректит на https

Comment: > "Страница начинает грузиться, появляется title но дальше редиректит на https" что за бред, как может страница грузится, появлятся TITLE и дальше редирект. Не может такого быть в принципе. При редиректе отдаются только заголовки HEADERS без тела

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov существует html-тег для редиректа

Comment: @andreymal `curl` это PHP он тут не причем.

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov а вообще фиг с ним с тегом, даже при нормальном http-редиректе иногда отдаётся тело, попробуйте выполнить `curl http://ru.stackoverflow.com/` в командной строке (curl это не только PHP, но и консольная команда)

Comment: @andreymal соглаен, но при этом идет редирект, тег который вы говорите `html`, при этом не исполнится.